# how to create sql statement from table which are present in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

how to create sql statement ?

say i have create a data base in MySQL and  i want to port it another database.
so i want convert my database to sql statement.

Comment: You mean you want to *export* your db ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html). It can do that and much more.

From the documentation:

> The mysqldump client [produces] a set of SQL statements that can be run to reproduce the original schema objects, table data, or both.